# How can I send the values ​of variables in the templates script to url in django?

Tags: python, django, jsp

In django, I would like to process {% url%} by putting the value of any variable in the TAG value of templates.

pp_001.html

```
<script>
$('#dataTables-wkgrid tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
    var data = table.row( this ).data();
    if ( $(this).hasClass('selected') ) {
       $(this).removeClass('selected');
    }
    else {
       table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
       $(this).addClass('selected');
       $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "{% url 'pp_02_open' %}",
       data : {
           "cPp_no" : data.pp_no
       },
       dataType: "json",
       cache: false,
       success: function(result){
       console.log(result) ;
       var aTag = "" ;
       $.each(result.filelist,function(index){
       cDocName  = result.filelist[index].doc_name ;                                 
       cFilename = result.filelist[index].file_name ;
       cid  = result.filelist[index].id  ;
       cpp_no = result.filelist[index].pp_no ;
       aTag += '<a href="{% url "pp_02_download" id=cid %}" class="list-group-item">'
            +'<i name="iText" class="fa fa-file-powerpoint-o fa-fw"></i>'+result.filelist[index].doc_name
            +'<i name="file_downloads" class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-download style="padding-left:10px">다운로드</i>'                      
            +'</span>'
            +'</a>'

</script>
```

urls.py

```
    path(r'^PP/download/<int:id>/$' , views_pp.download , name="pp_02_download"),
```

ERROR....

Reverse for 'pp_02_download' with keyword arguments '{'id': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['crms/\^PP\/download\/(?P[0-9]+)\/\$$']

In other words, when the value of the variable of jsp script is 
{% url "pp_02_download id = cid%}, I wonder how it is possible to pass the value of cid.

If you pass "10" randomly instead of cid in this way, it will execute normally.

Comment: Please share your `views_pp.download` function, I think that is where you need to make changes.

Comment: Since you are using django2, urls.py can be as: `path('PP/download/<int:id>/' , views_pp.download , name="pp_02_download"),`

Comment: path('PP/download/<int:id>/' , views_pp.download , name="pp_02_download"),
urls.py에 대한 변경은 작동하지 않습니다.

Comment: Please stop posting updates as answers to your question. Delete those three answers and *edit* your question with the new information. Although it is acceptable to answer your own question, answers must actually be answers and not updates.

Answer (score 0):

Development is not yet complete. First, it takes an id value in the paramter, retrieves the data, and then tries to download the file.

The current source is configured to be able to check whether downloading is normal by specifying only specific files at will.

views.py

```
def download(request,id):
    # filename = 'files/test.py'
    filename = 'files/테스트.pptx'
    file_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, filename)
    # file_path = reduce(os.path.join, (settings.MEDIA_ROOT, filename))
    logger.info('file_path : %s' , file_path )
    if os.path.exists(file_path) and os.path.isfile(file_path):
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as fp:
            response = HttpResponse(fp.read())
        content_type, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(filename)
        if content_type is None:
            content_type = 'application/octet-stream'
        # content_type = ""
        response['Content-Type'] = content_type
        response['Content-Length'] = str(os.stat(file_path).st_size)
        logger.info('content_type : %s' , content_type )

    # encoding = 'euc-kr'
    logger.info("encoding : %s" , encoding )
    if encoding is not None:
        response['Content-Encoding'] = encoding
    else:
        response['Content-Encoding'] = 'euc-kr'

    if u'WebKit'in request.META.get('HTTP_USER_AGENT', u'Webkit'):
        filename = os.path.basename(filename)
        filename_header = 'filename=%s' % os.path.basename(filename)
    elif u'MSIE' in request.META.get('HTTP_USER_AGENT', u'MSIE'):
        filename_header = ''
        filename_header = 'filename=%s' % os.path.basename(filename)
    else:
        filename_header = 'filename=%s' % os.path.basename(filename)

    filename_header = filename_header.encode('cp949')   # utf -> euc 로 변환

    response['Content-Disposition'] = filename_header
    logger.info('filename-header : %s ' , filename_header )
    logger.info('[Content-Disposition] : %s' , response['Content-Disposition'])

    return response
```

Answer (score 0):

```
path(r'PP/download/<int:id>/' , views_pp.download , name="pp_02_download"),
```

Changes to urls.py will not work.

NoReverseMatch at /crms/PP/
Reverse for 'pp_02_download' with keyword arguments '{'id': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['crms/PP\/download\/(?P[0-9]+)\/$']